# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "cv::String::deallocate()"

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

When I add a ".a" file which includes opencv.framework,Xcode encountered such compile errors:

[image]

I am pretty sure opencv.framework is there,and I am using opencv 3.1,it should already support arm64. But why does it keep complaining about this? How can I fix it? Thanks a lot.

lipo - info shows following information:
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/Fumin/libVisageWrapper.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64

Comment: In your project settings, can you confirm that the library is being linked during the Linking-phase?
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html

Comment: Yes, I've double-check that. The library is being linked correctly.

Comment: I just noticed that the LD error is "symbol(s) not found for architecture", Is it possible the framework doesn't support arm64?
Eg: it only has x86/x86_64 support? Or your using the wrong version of the framework?

Comment: The latest OpenCV iOS framework supports 64 bit by default, and I am using iOS version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is already an opencv library in some other library,so two instance opencvs are conflictting with each other. After .a file provider provide a new version using the same opencv library, now it works fine.

Comment: can u please explain better? What are the steps you took?

Comment: Suppose you have two library files:  "libOne.a" and "libTwo.a", and they both contain the same opencv library, in that circumstances there will be conflicts, so you have to talk to one of these two library providers, tell them to remove the opencv library for you, since there is already one opencv libray inside another library for you. @Francesco Boi

Comment: Confirming this resolves the problem when building from source the `opencv_viz` module on the Mac, with an older version of OpenCV installed in `/usr/local/lib` via Homebrew. To solve the problem one must `brew uninstall opencv`, then build from source, then bring the old version back if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You should verify that the library is correctly supporting arm64 using this command:

```
lipo -info libYourLib.a
```

The output of this command should show this:

```
Architectures in the fat file: libYourLib.a are: armv7 arm64
```

A *fat* file means a file which holds binary elements for possibly more than one architecture.

If arm64 is missing, you can't build a target for arm64 devices. You might need to ask your supplier of the library to build a *fat* version which includes the arm64 architecture.

Comment: I've used this command, it says arm64 is supported. So it should be something else causes this error.

Comment: Architectures in the fat file: /Users/Fumin/libVisageWrapper.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64

Comment: So @Li Fumin we have learned from your answer below that these "Undefined Symbols" could sometimes be due to more than one .a file providing the same API's. BTW You can learn a lot on the content of '.a' file by running `otool -P libYourLib.a`